# Buscar registros por fechas con MaskEdit [delphi ]

Tags: delphi

Estoy intentando buscar registro por fecha con dos MaskEdit por medio de un botón

```
Begin
datasourse.dataset.filtered := false;
if MaskEdit1 = '' and maskEdit2 = '' then
begin
datasourse.dataset.filter := // en esta linea como paso  parametro fecha a los  dos MaskEdit
datasourse.dataset.filtered := true;
end;
end;
```

mi duda es como paso como parametro el campo fecha teniendo los MaskEdit

Comment: ¿Los `MaskEdit` son componentes de tipo TMaskEdit? ¿cuál es el criterio que debe cumplir el registro que buscas con respecto de los valores ingresados en los `MaskEdit`? ¿Cuál es la estructura de tu DataSet?

Comment: Los criterio que debe cumplir es el   campo fecha, no se si es posible pasar dos parametros "fecha1" y "fecha2" como si fuera un Tdatetimepicker

Comment: Por favor, pablo, te hice 3 preguntas y no has respondido ninguna. Si hay un campo fecha, cómo ubicas al registro que quieres buscar con 2 fechas? O más bien quieres encontrar todos los registros que estén en el rango de fechas de fecha1 y fecha2? o qué es lo que buscas? Agradezco que vayas respondiendo mis preguntas una a una. Un saludo.

Comment: 1)Si es un control  TMaskEdit 2) Lo que busco hacer es encontrar todo registros que estén en fecha1 y fecha2 3)  no comprendo la pregunta (soy algo nuevo en esto ).

Answer (score 1):

Para pasar el texto de los `MaskEdit` como filtro al `DataSet`, para obtener todos los registros que tengan el campo `Fecha` dentro del rango de fechas, puedes construir una cadena para incluir todas las fechas que sean mayores o iguales al texto de `MaskEdit1` y que sean menores o iguales al texto de `MaskEdit2`.

Al final, el valor de la propiedad `Filter` tiene que ser algo parecido a esto:

```
(Fecha >= '01/01/2019') and (Fecha <= '31/12/2019')
```

Como puedes observar, las fechas se pasan como cadenas de caracteres, incluyendo los `'` que las encierran, dentro del texto de la propiedad, que es un `string`.

Para construir esta cadena, puedes valerte de las funciones `Format()` y `QuotedStr()`, de la unidad `strUtils`.

El código quedaría algo como esto:

```
begin
  DataSource.DataSet.Filter := '';
  if (MaskEdit1.Text <> '  /  /    ') and (MaskEdit2.Text <> '  /  /    ') then
  begin
    DataSource.DataSet.Filter := Format('(Fecha >= %s) and (Fecha <= %s)', [QuotedStr(MaskEdit1.Text), QuotedStr(MaskEdit2.Text)])
    DataSource.DataSet.Filtered := True;
  end;
end;
```

He puesto la comparación de los `MaskEdit` con cadenas `'  /  /    '` y no con cadenas vacías `''`, porque recuerdo que así funciona ese componente, que yo hace mucho que no uso. Si eso no es correcto, te queda a ti adaptar el código.

Dicho todo esto, realmente sugiero no utilizar componentes de tipo MaskEdit para pedir las fechas al usuario. En principio, puede parecer conveniente, pero a medida que la audiencia de tu aplicación crece, vas a encontrarte con personas que manejan la fecha en diferentes formatos, `dd/mm/aaaa` en América Latina, `mm/dd/yyyy` en Estados Unidos, `dd.mm.yyyy` en Alemania, por poner unos pocos ejemplos.

Es mejor utilizar un `DateTimePicker` u otro componente especializado en manejar fechas, que de fábrica utilizará el formato de fecha configurado en el Windows del usuario, y utilizar variables de tipo `TDateTime` en tu lógica interna.

En el filtro, al final de cuentas, la fecha siempre se *pasa* como una cadena, con el formato de fecha *default* del programa, si utilizaras DateTimePicker, el código podría lucir como:

```
    DataSource.DataSet.Filter := Format('(Fecha >= %s) and (Fecha <= %s)', [QuotedStr(DateToString(DateTimePicker1.Date)), QuotedStr(DateToString(DateTimePicker2.Date))])
```